# How to handle UDP and HTTP2 requests in Springboot using Netty

Tags: spring-boot, udp, http2, udpclient, reactor-netty

Using Springboot with Netty for UDP messaging try to achieve below use cases:

[image]

App1 communicating with App2 Via HTTP2 on 8080 port

App2 communicating with App3 Via UDP req on 8805 port

After reading UDP response in App2 at messageReceived method, try to figure out how to send UDP response back to http2 req for App1.

PFB code snippet.

@RestController
public class UdpToHttpController {

```
@GetMapping("/api/udp-to-http")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleUdpToHttp() {
    try {
        // Create a UDP listener to receive the UDP response
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(group)
                .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
                .handler(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg) {
                        // Extract the necessary information from the UDP response
                        ByteBuf content = msg.content();
                        String udpResponse = content.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

                        // Construct an HTTP request
                        FullHttpRequest httpRequest = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, "/api/endpoint");
                        httpRequest.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.HOST, "example.com");
                        httpRequest.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
                        httpRequest.content().writeBytes(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(udpResponse, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

                        // Send the HTTP request to the desired endpoint
                        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                        FullHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.send(httpRequest, "example.com");

                        // Process the HTTP response
                        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.valueOf(httpResponse.status().code());
                        String responseBody = httpResponse.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

                        // Construct and return the HTTP response
                        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, responseHeaders, httpStatus);
                    }
                });

        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.bind(5000).sync(); // Specify the UDP port to listen on
        future.channel().closeFuture().await();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error occurred");
    }
}
```